# GitHub Problems Parsing JSON Command-Line Mac 10.6.8

Tags: macos, curl, command-line, github, osx-snow-leopard

I'm having a problem creating a repo on GitHub using `curl`.  I think I'm formatting it correctly but I keep getting back "Problems parsing JSON" Here's what I'm doing:

```
Zachary-Dunhams-MacBook:foo zacharydunham$ curl -u 'ZachDunham' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":foo"}'
```

> Enter host password for user 'ZachDunham': {   "message": "Problems
>   parsing JSON",   "documentation_url": "http://developer.github.com/v3"

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://gitref.org/creating/

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is missing a quote

```
{"name":foo"}
        ^
```

So add it :

```
{
    "name": "foo"
}
```